# Assign fixed value to parameter in RouteConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to assign a fixed value to a parameter within my `ASP.NET` routing configuration class?

How could I achieve something to this effect:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "createFile",
            url: "create/file",
            defaults: new { controller = "create", 
                            action = "newFile", 
                            string fixedParameter = "blue"}       
          );
```

Instead of typing `www.example.com/create/file?fixedParameter=blue`

I would like to test the same `URL` with just `www.example.com/create/file`

Do I need to put something like:

```
string fixedParameter = UrlParameter.Equals("blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The 'constraints' parameter is what I was looking for. Thus I would have:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "createFile",
        url: "create/file",
        constraints: new
        {
           fixedParameter = "blue"
        },
        defaults: new { controller = "create", action = "newFile"}       
      );
```